# How do I use RestSharp to deserialize class hierarchies?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, restsharp

The HTTP response (text/xml):

```
<results>
  <status code="ok"/>
  <OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN>
    <token>db8288c2e01a6e0caa5a9b52cc4570040b2714cc7a1f589670d6606d486ab98e</token>
  </OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN>
</results>
```

My C# objects:

```
[DeserializeAs(Name = "results")]
public class Response
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "status")]
    public ResultStatus Status { get; set; }

    public struct ResultStatus
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}

internal class AuthenticationResponse : Response
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN")]
    internal OWaspCsrfToken CsrfToken { get; set; }

    internal struct OWaspCsrfToken
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "token")]
        internal string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The goal here is to have RestSharp deserialize the HTTP response to objects in code. However, for some reason only the result status's `Code` property is being properly set; the `Token` property is always `null`. What's the proper way to deserialize objects in class hierarchies like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the use of `internal`. My guess is that properties, classes, and methods marked `internal` can't even be properly sniffed using reflection at runtime. Or, if they can be, RestSharp might have an issue doing this correctly. In any case, this works:

```
public class AuthenticationResponse : Response
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN")]
    public OWaspCsrfToken CsrfToken { get; set; }

    public struct OWaspCsrfToken
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "token")]
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Actually, I'm pretty sure reflection can see the internal methods. The problem was that RestSharp can't call the set method on any of the internal properties.